# Need help : Mail command in unix Bteq to customize from address

Tags: email, unix

Accordig to my script,I need to send a mail incase if there is a failure inside bteq.I already tried this command,but it isn't working.Kindly help.

```
.os mailx -s "$(echo "Insufficient Space : - Add Space\nFrom: Build <xyz@ppp.qqq.rrr.com>\n")" "zzzzz@yyy.com" </dev/null
```

error :

```
 *** Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the word 'mailx'.
```

Please let me know if im making any mistake here.

Comment: Check this--->http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/script-to-send-a-mail-to-the-recipients-in-bteq

Answer (score 0):

```
.os mailx -s "$(echo \"Insufficient Space : - Add Space\nFrom: Build <xyz@ppp.qqq.rrr.com>\n\")" "zzzzz@yyy.com" </dev/null
```

Update the command as above I hope it would work.

Comment: Im still facing the below error
 `sh: xyz@ppp.qqq.rrr.com: cannot open
 *** Warning: System call failed.`

Answer (score 0):

somehow I was able to make it to work using the below command.Thanks for the help .

> .os mailx -r "" -s "Insufficient Space : - Add Space"